# Retrieving multiple images from isolated storage in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to retrieve multiple images from isolated storage using listbox but i am not sure why it just only retrieve the lastest image from isolated storage.Therefore hope anyone could help me make amends to my code or could provide me with sample code that works which is about the same as mine.Thanks.

My code :

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage(string imageFolder, string imageFileName )
{ 

  var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
  if (!isoFile.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))

{
  isoFile.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
}

  string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageFileName);
  using (var imageStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
  BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
  ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
  bi.SetSource(imageStream);
  item.Content = new Image() 
{ 
  Source = bi, MaxHeight = 100, MaxWidth = 100 };
  listBox1.Items.Add(item);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving multiple image from isolated storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436690/retrieving-multiple-image-from-isolated-storage)

Comment: hard to tell w/o seeing how the listbox or ViewModel calls LoadFromLocalStorage

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you tell what results are you getting.

- Do you see only 1 element?
- Do you see multiple elements and they are the same?
- Do you see multiple elements and only 1 shows a picture and other are empty?

Anyway this is not a proper way to treat listbox. But first things first.
This line doesn't do anything useful:

```
var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);
```

This code should work (it seems), but there may be an error outside the code. How many times this function is called and what parameters are passed - that is what actually matters.

But I would change the code to use Data Binding and proper ItemsSource.

1. Create class for items

   ```
   public class MyImage 
   { 
       public string FilePath {get; set;} 
       public ImageSource LoadedSource {get; set;} 
   }
   ```
2. Create an **ObservableCollection<MyImage>()** and fill it with your data.
3. Bind it to **ListBox** by setting **ItemsSource**
4. Design a proper ItemTemplate with Image and Binding:

   ```
   <Image Source={Binding LoadedSource}/>
   ```

This setup will help you debug the issues easily and localize the problem. It is likely that you are calling your original function incorrectly.