# Retrieving multiple image from isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am saving image into isolated storage each image have a different imageFileName. But i am having problem to retrieve all the saved image in a listbox.
Only managed to retrieve the latest image saved.
When i hard code the filepath then can retrieve it.
I hope anyoen can help me with the code.. Hopefully anyone can try editing my code. Thanks.

Save code:

```
private void SaveToLocalStorage(string imageFolder, string imageFileName)
        {
            imageFileName = App.imagePath;

            var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (!isf.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
            {
                isf.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
            }

            string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageFileName);
            using (var stream = isf.CreateFile(filePath))
            {
                var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(inkCanvas, inkCanvas.RenderTransform);
                bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(filePath            }
```

Retrieve code:

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage(string imageFolder, string imageFileName )
        {
            var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (!isoFile.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
            {
                isoFile.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
            }

            string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageFileName);
            using (var imageStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

                ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
                bi.SetSource(imageStream);
                item.Content = new Image() { Source = bi, MaxHeight = 100, MaxWidth = 100 };
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage(string imageFolder)
{
    var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    // Check if directory exists
    if(!isoFile.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
    {
        throw new Exception("Image directory not found");
    }

    // Clear listbox
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    // Get files
    foreach(string fileName in isoFile.GetFileNames())
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, fileName);
        using(var imageStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);

            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

            ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
            bi.SetSource(imageStream);
            item.Content = new Image() { Source = bi, MaxHeight = 100, MaxWidth = 100 };
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi.. is it possible to retrieve specify image out?? like retrieving only the second or third from the isolated storage

Comment: @ben tan: Sure, just add an `if()` condition inside the `foreach()` that `continue;`'s if the image should be ignored...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing more of your code, but it looks like you're only retrieving one file. Elsewhere in your code are you getting a list of all of the files that should be in the IsolateStorage directory and looping through them? Are you seeing any error messages, or is it just failing silently?

Comment: This is the code for my saving button..
SaveToLocalStorage("imageFolder", App.imagePath);

And this is the code for my retrieving button..
LoadFromLocalStorage("imageFolder", imageFileName);

There is no other code..
How should i go about doing the looping and getting the list of all files in the directory??
There is no error.

Can u provide me with a example?? Or can just edit on the code.. Thank.. Will appreciate it..

Comment: @Evon Chong: 'App.imagePath' sounds like a static string or URI variable so it contains only one image path. No wonder you get only one image. You need a collection of string or URI to iterate over and retrieve every single image.

Comment: my App.imagePath is App.imagePath = String.Format("PhotoNote_{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.jpg", DateTime.Now);

Comment: hmm.. how should i modify my code?? can u help me with it?? thank